# Brand-new triage audits need comment trimming

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-audits, triage

So apparently triage has audits now.

However, they don't take out comments like the other queues do, so are kind of obvious most of the time. This should probably be fixed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not all review queues hide comments in their audits. As far as I know, it's just the First Posts and Late Answers audits that do so. Those review queues are pretty unusual all around.

There's been some debate about showing comments on audits:

- [Should audits not scrub comments from the question/answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240036/should-audits-not-scrub-comments-from-the-question-answer)
- [Late Answers audits should show comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228932/late-answers-audits-should-show-comments)

My gut feeling is, they should be visible *if we do a good job of choosing the posts used for them* - for instance, avoiding obvious duplicates for known-good audits and self-deleted questions for known-bad. If you're reading all the way down to the comments, you probably *should* pass the audit (and if you fail even after reading the comments, shame on you).

Comment: I may be wrong, but they both look Pro Showing to me.

Comment: OK, fair enough.

Comment: Good catch, @santa

Comment: It's no shame to fail an audit after an honest effort to understand the question. Failed audits should be a learning experience. Shame is counter-productive.

Comment: Audits also should not be difficult nor designed to trip you up. I have been involved in numerous audits of aerospace procedures which has potential life or death consequences. An audit should be designed to tell if you are following the procedure, not if you arrive at the right answer. People are going to get it wrong every now and again.