# A problem in the 'first post' answer audit

Tags: feature-request

I was reviewing "first posts" and came across this answer (which later turned out to be an "audit"):

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7873412

As it appears in the "first posts" review, the question is shown, and the answer is shown. It looks like a valid answer, or a well-intentioned attempt to answer. So I chose "No Action Needed".

Later it turned out that this was a *duplicate answer* as the comments show, and therefore I failed the audit. Category-wise, it is a "low-quality" answer. Why didn't I notice it earlier? Because the other answers were not shown, so it so appeared that this seems to be the only answer. In fact if it were, then it was perhaps the right answer too, as it matches in parts to the other upvoted answers.

There are two things I would like to request:

1. If the post to be reviewed is an answer, please make all the answers available in the view, in addition to the question. This will facilitate noticing duplicate answers. Even in the result page of the failed audit, there is only this answer, no others. It is only by looking at the comments (or actually opening up the question page in a separate tab), that one can find the other answers.
2. In the result box telling me about the failure, there is only one button: "I understand". Should there be some way to say "I think I was right"? Because heuristic algorithms to judge human behaviours can go wrong.

This is the first audit that I have failed, so I guess it does not matter much.

**Edit in response to being marked as duplicate:** I am not asking *why* it failed. This was about how the system *should* present first posts, audit or otherwise. In the main, with all answers. And after considering the now accepted answer, I am (for the time being) convinced that it's not needed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed and banned for user who answered the question correctly?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288592/failed-and-banned-for-user-who-answered-the-question-correctly)

Comment: @gnat Nah, that question asks why the audit failed, and the question that it in turn is marked duplicate of, are general guidelines. My point was none of these. I perfectly understand why the system evaluated my audit as failed, and I am not asking a "why" question. My point was the system did not give enough information (all the answers) at the time of testing. After going through the accepted answer, I am (for the time being) satisfied that it indeed did.

Comment: "You are _expected_ to take some time to help guide a new user in the first posts review. Clicking 'no action needed' reinforces bad habits when they are there... You have 20 reviews per day for this queue - it's not a race to get through them. Spending less than 10 seconds per review is not the focus of this review queue..."

Comment: I agree that [the lack of (other) answers in review is a problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172931/please-put-answers-underneath-questions-in-close-review-queue). In fact, I found it annoying enough that I added [a client-side fix](http://stackapps.com/a/4595) for it into [SOUP](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The comments on the answer are visible in the review queue, and they make clear that the answer is a duplicate. The poster even admits that it is a duplicate. So, there is enough information on-screen to detect the low quality of the answer.

In this case, the audit tests if you were really paying attention to the context. I think it's a pretty difficult one, but I also think it's a fair and doable one.

Also, the audits aren't simply based on heuristics; they are drawn from posts that have already been handled by a moderator or by the community. Every now and then one is really wrong, in which case you should post about it here on Meta. In practice, though, that's pretty rare.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for pointing that out! I read the question, and I read the answer, but didn't look at the comments. In this case the comments were clear. But wouldn't it be good to show all the answers in answer review?

Comment: It's not usually necessary; each answer should stand on its own, so the other answers only really matter if the answer you are reviewing is a duplicate, like this one. In that case, one of two things almost always will happen: (1) there will be comments, like there were here, or (2) someone will flag it for moderator attention (for plagiarism, for example). In the first case, you have the information you need. In the second case, the flag goes to a moderator, not to the reveiw queue.

Comment: Thanks. I vaguely remember that the comments were stripped out for the audit purpose, but now its difficult to reproduce, so I won't claim it. Will keep what you said in mind.

Comment: The comments *should* always be visible. Definitely post on Meta if you find an instance that depends on the comments but where the comments aren't visible! Good question, btw.

Comment: @Abhay: Also of interest: [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts), which shows that in FPQ and LAQ you really need to dig a bit unless things are obvious.

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks...This one also answered some of my other questions, esp "utter misunderstanding of one or more fundamentals".

Comment: @EdCottrell: Audits frequently do depend on comments, and *FP and LA audits will never show comments*. This appears to be by design, and these queues are specifically different from others in this way. (I don't agree with that design, but there it is.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Actually, that's not entirely correct. I just looked at the FP queue, found a question there, posted a comment, and refreshed my browser tab for the FP review. The comment does appear with the question. [Here's a screenshot](http://imgur.com/Aq4YjRY). Don't worry, I deleted my bogus comment.

Comment: @NathanTuggy [Here's a second example, with only legitimate comments](http://imgur.com/VfD6vAB).

Comment: @EdCottrell: Only legitimate reviews will ever show comments. Audits? Won't. Consistency? What's that?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Hmm. I see what you're saying, now. I haven't ever run across this, to my knowledge, but that does sound strange. Is there a prior discussion on this? (Edit: I have looked, but I couldn't find one.)

Comment: @EdCottrell: [Yes and no.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284308/4099598)

Comment: FWIW one can argue that [selection of known-bad audits looks more reliable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204736/165773) than that of known good ones. "there is a bit of disbalance related to the fact that voting down requires higher reputation than voting up, suggesting that on average voters down (who feed into known-bad audits) can be expected to have stronger understanding of site quality norms. Worth keeping in mind that voting to close questions requires even higher reputation and that voting answer down carries a rep penalty, as opposed to totally free upvoting..."