# Triage Audit: Bug or Feature?

Tags: discussion

I had this in the Triage Review Queue today. I've been around here for some months now, so I know that if Frank N. Stein says it's SPAM then it's just that.
Even although I have read ["Brand-new triage audits need comment trimming"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284307) and also ["Late Answers audits should show comments"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228932) **and** agree with their point of view in general, I woul like to ask:

Maybe it's possible not to show the comments in such cases? It would be much more fun that way. 
[image: the screenshot says it all]

As for the tag, I wasn't so sure about that. Feel free to change it :)

Comment: Mr. Stein shouldn't have close-voted, but flagged as spam, instead.

Comment: @Cerbrus - The point is that *with the comment* this is not a good audit question

Comment: I think it makes an excellent audit question, even with the comment. (See my answer)

Comment: Easy audits aren't (usually) due to bugs, see [This review is obviously an audit. Is this a bug?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug)

Comment: ok, @Kendra, I admit I'm complaining because I feel bereaved of that "tremendous sense of accomplishment" j08691 spoke of ;) This one was  just too easy

Comment: Time to change my name to Frank N Stein and post some comments... _bwa ha ha_

Comment: @Luke - I think you could. There are lots of "Sam"s out there. Don't forget the "." though ;)

Comment: @all - I'm a little bit uncertain whether finding the link to "This review..." would have stopped me from posting this question. This audit question is not fit to guide new users because it might lead them to blindly follow the judgement of a high-rep user. I would prefer it if they had to use their own brain. But on the other hand - learning to swim by imitating a swimmer - why not? On the other other hand, I should not expect too much of audit questions. If they serve one of two purposes, that should be enough. Shouldn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those audits are meant to filter out those users that aren't paying attention, the robo-reviewers.
They're not meant to be difficult.

I don't really see the need to "fix" this.

Comment: robo-reviewers? You mean this is about whether I am human?

Comment: No, these audits are meant to check if you're paying attention when reviewing.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I'm beginning to suspect that there must be persons who do nothing but klick "Looks OK" or "Requires Editing", because that way they get nearer to their next bagde.

Comment: Exactly, and that's why those audits are there :-)

Comment: Well, they don't *need* to be hunting the badge to need a warning. They might just be starting to slip due to repetition leading to review-trance.